# Creating equal area groups of GIS points

Tags: python, arcgis, qgis

I have point data (~1400 points) where each point represents the area of a feature. I want to group these points into let's say 20 groups such that each group have an equal total area (i.e., the sum of areas of all points in a group).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Preferenced tools: Python or ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). I searched for an implementation and there is something called [numberpartitioning](https://github.com/fuglede/numberpartitioning) on PyPI that you could try out, however that pertains specifically to partitioning a list. Given the size of your input, I imagine only an approximate solution can be found.

For graph partitioning, check out [METIS](https://metis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I found it implemented in a project called [GIS-tools](https://pypi.org/project/gis-tools/), which I'm assuming is closer to what you're looking for.

A proprietary solution is available through ArcGIS Pro named "Build Balanced Zones" which is part of their [Mapping Clustering Toolset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/an-overview-of-the-mapping-clusters-toolset.htm). It uses a genetic algorithm, so each random seed may produce different results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mine is a spatial case where I need to group neighbouring points based on their area summation. Therefore, I am looking for a spatial algorithm.
Nevertheless, thanks for the initial direction.

Comment: Updated my post. I hope that info is closer what you're looking for. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for this. I found a tool in ArcGIS Pro, called "Build Balanced Zones".

Comment: That's neat! I will update my post to include this for future readers. Their website says it uses a genetic algorithm--this makes sense because it would likely require too much computation to get precise answers for larger inputs. That tool is also mentioned at [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331858/looking-for-qgis-equivalent-of-arcgis-pro-build-balanced-zones-tool), so if you have future GIS-specific questions I'm guessing they're the folks to ask.